# hping send SYN: how not to send RST after receiving SYN/ACK?

Tags: sockets, tcp, hping

using hping, I send SYN packet, second peer is listening and replies with SYN/ACK, but hping (or linux kernel does it I guess) sends RST after receiving SYN/ACK.

Is there anyway I can stop my machine sending RST after receiving SYN/ACK?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command should drop any TCP packet with the `RST` flag set your machine would send to the specific destination:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -d <destination> -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP
```

to revert it, use:

```
iptables -D OUTPUT -d <destination> -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP
```

---

An alternative is to block all incoming TCP packets with `SYN`+`ACK` flags set from the specific source (i.e. the packets that cause the `RST`):

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -s <source> -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK SYN,ACK -j DROP
```

to revert it, use:

```
iptables -D INPUT -s <source> -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK SYN,ACK -j DROP
```

---

Works for me with `hping3 -S -p 22 <destination>`